# Which tab event fires in visible tab?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

In a Chrome extension i'm trying to find a combination of events, which listener would cover tab activation, tab creation and tab update, but only in case the tab is visible.

Until now i use a combination of

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
    if (changeInfo.url) run(tab);
});

chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(info => {
    chrome.tabs.get(info.tabId, run);
});
```

This combination mismatchs my needs, because `onUpdated` fires even if there is a background tab opened.

How can i adjust the event combination to fire events only in a tab visible for user?

The whole background.js:

```
var currentDomain = "";
var currentHost = "";
var currentFullpath = "";
var currentUrl = "";
var currentFolder = "";
var badgeText = "";
var currentProtocol ="";
const processingTabId = {};

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
    chrome.windows.get(tab.windowId, (window)=> {
        if (window.focused && changeInfo.url) run(tab);
    })
});


chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(info => {
    chrome.tabs.get(info.tabId, run);
});

function run(tab) {
    if (processingTabId[tab.id]) return;
    processingTabId[tab.id] = true;

    let newUrl = new URL(tab.pendingUrl || tab.url)
    currentHost = newUrl.host;
    currentUrl = tab.url;
    currentProtocol = newUrl.protocol;

    currentFullpath = currentUrl.substring(0, currentUrl.lastIndexOf("/"));
    currentFolder = currentUrl.split("/");
    parsed = psl.parse(currentHost);
    currentDomain = parsed.domain;

    chrome.storage.sync.get('savedApi', ({
        savedApi
    }) => {

        if (savedApi == undefined){
            savedApi = "de";
        }

/*  console.log(savedApi); */

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var protocol = "https://";
        var middle = ".myservice.com/seo/__loadModule/domain/"
        var end = "/mobile/1/_action/_data_visindex_normal/";

        xhr.open("GET", protocol + savedApi + middle + currentDomain + end, true);

        xhr.responseType = 'document';

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
console.log(xhr);
            if (this.readyState == 4 && xhr.status !== 500) {

                function getElementByXpath(path) {
                    return xhr.response.evaluate(path, xhr.response, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null).stringValue;
                }

                badgeText = getElementByXpath("normalize-space(//div[@class='data']/span[@class='value']/text())");
                chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({
                    text: String(badgeText)
                });



                chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({
                    color: '#1d2554'
                });

                if (badgeText == "") {
                    chrome.browserAction.setTitle({
                        title: "Sistrix login required!"
                    });

                } else {
                    chrome.browserAction.setTitle({
                        title: "Data of " + currentDomain + " is " + String(badgeText)
                    });

                }

            }
            delete processingTabId[tab.id];
        }

if (currentDomain && currentProtocol.indexOf("http") ===0) {
xhr.send();
        }

    })
}
```

Comment: `onUpdated` passes [`Tab`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#type-Tab) object (to callback) which contain all the info you might need (see `active` property).

Comment: @hindmost, correct, tried to do so. But run into another issue: if i activate the tab through click on it in the tab bar, without to do anything other, `onUpdated` doesn't fire.

Comment: _if i activate the tab through click on it in the tab bar..._ Then `onActivated` should fire, not `onUpdated`.

Comment: @hindmost exactly - thats why the combination of two event listeners. But `onUpdated` fires if the tab is opened as background tab - what i want to prevent.

Comment: tbh, I can't understand what your problem is

Comment: The problem is: `onUpdated` fires even if there is a background tab opened. I want an event or combination of events, which fires only if a tab is visible, in foreground.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to filter `onUpdated` event from background tabs, you can request info about the window the updated tab belongs to, by [`windows.get`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#method-get) method. It returns [`Window`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#type-Window) object containing all info about the requested window, incl. `focused` property you looking for. The requested window ID may be obtained via `tab` argument of `onUpdated` callback.

So the code should look like this:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
    chrome.windows.get(tab.windowId, (window)=> {
        if (window.focused && changeInfo.url) run(tab);
    })
});
```

Comment: К сожалению without effect. It fires with background tab too. I add the whole code of background.js to my post - it becomes maybe more clear.

Comment: You have two `onUpdated` listeners there, and the first (old) one calls `run` unconditionally. That's why "It fires with background tab too".

Comment: it was a copypaste fail. indeed there is only one `onUpdated`

Comment: Well. Then it's time for debugging. Are you familiar with debugging?